# Are there any references of robots in Ancient India?

Tags: history, science

I know that our ancestors in Ancient India (Bharath)  were advanced. I just wanna know if there are any references of robots in our Hindu Scriptures?

Comment: Why would a man need mobile phones if they have telepathic abilities. Such is the case. They didn't need Robots.. Vedic yagnas were so powerful that they could directly manifest a real being who would do their work...for eg. Draupad manifested Dristadyumna from yagya for the purpose of killing Dronacharya... there are also other many examples...

Comment: @Tezz Vyasa and Dristadyumna were exceptions. The Mahabharata war was mostly fought on foot using human soldiers, mahouts, charioteers and such. I'm sure robots would have come handy ;)

Comment: See my answer here for some probable robots: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42900/how-do-daityas-and-danavas-look-what-is-their-physical-appearance/43305#43305

Answer (score 4):

The [Indian Lokapannatti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_robots#Early_legends) (11th/12th century) tells the story of King Ajatashatru of Magadha who gathered the Buddhas relics and hid them in an underground stupa. The Buddha's relics were protected by [mechanical robots (bhuta vahana yanta)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ItxjAAAAMAAJ&dq=ashoka%20robots&source=gbs_book_other_versions), from the kingdom of Roma visaya; until they were disarmed by King Ashoka.

Comment: Good find but i think OP is interested in references from Hindu Scriptures.

Comment: Their is also story related with a pope having built a binary machine which can give the answers in yes /no format. with ref. from sanskrit shlokas or from India. 1000 A. D.

Answer (score -2):

When the Vanaras saw Kumbhakrana, they fled. Then Vibhisana told Rama the following words -

> "Let’s tell all the monkeys that he is just some **giant mechanical man**. Once they accept that, they will lose their fear of him." - Valmiki Ramayana VI.49.31

Source:

The Ramayana of Valmiki: An Epic of Ancient India Volume VI (Yuddhakanda). Page No. 271. Translation and annotation by Robert P. Goldman, Sally J. Sutherland Goldman and Barend A. van Nooten. Princeton University Press. Princeton and Oxford. 2009. ([Link](https://b-ok.asia/book/5909507/e52df3?dsource=recommend))