# Does being alive have a definition?

Tags: vedas, scripture, upanishads, life, consciousness

Humanity is at the advent of developing Self Aware Artificial Intelligence. What do ancient scriptures, sayings, traditions etc. Tell us about the definition of being a living entity? Will self conscious machines be "living" in the eyes of ancients?

Comment: No self aware artificial intelligence has occurred to date. As such, your question is of the nature of scientific speculation, which is not allowed on this site.

Comment: I think Sankhya tells a thing becomes conscious when Purush enters in it... I think Vedanta tells there is not such thing as nonliving... everything possesses intellect and mind to some level... even that thing which we call nonliving...

Comment: [Related not duplicate] [Are there any references of robots in Ancient India?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11359/3500)

Comment: Looks like your question's title and body are bit unrelated. Can you edit your title?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because now question is asking definition of **Chaitanya** (conscious) and **Jada**....

Comment: @ Tezz is right , and moreover , Lets see if we can give the Satisfactory answer , lets try !